# The button can't access. How to fix this code?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, class, if-statement, actionscript

I am a newbie in AS3. I dont have a good basic in AS3. 
What's wrong with my code?
There is no error!
Help me, please.

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Button;


    public class gantiGambar extends MovieClip{
        public function gantiGambar(){
            // constructor code
            pertama();
        }

        public function pertama():void{
            lantai2.visible = false;
            lantai1.visible = false;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
            lantai1.visible = true;     
        }

        if(lantai1.onClick == 1){
            lantai2.visible = true;
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a listener to stage, while the class is likely not added to stage yet, thus `stage` is null and no reaction can be received. First, you should `addEventListener` to the instance, not to the stage
And second, put the code with `if (lantai1.onClick==1)` into the handler, or it won't be called.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    lantai1.visible = true;     
    if(lantai1.onClick == 1) {
        lantai2.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer adds a listener to stage ;)

Comment: That's what happens if you abuse copy&paste from question. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've tried your code but nothing happened.

Comment: Does your `lantai1`'s parent have anything visible? If nothing is visible, the listener won't trigger. Also, what is `lantai1.onClick`? If it's a number, you have to set it somewhere.

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it. 
I change my code became like this:
package  {
 
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 public class BallJumper extends MovieClip {
  public function BallJumper(){
   setup();
  }
  
  private function setup():void{
   popup.visible = false;
   this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
  }

  private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
   if(key.onClick == 1){
    popup.visible = true;
   }
     }
 }
}

Comment: I changed the "lantai1" to "key"

Comment: Anyway, what are you checking to be equal 1? What it should be? It will not work until the value of `key.onClick` will be equal to 1, and I don't see how do you set this value, if ever.

Comment: Actually, I want make if the button "key" clicked, it will show the mc of "popup". That's what I mean to. Could you help me, @Vesper? Thank you

Comment: You should then attach your listener directly to "key" object. `key.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick); function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void { popup.visible=true; }`

Comment: thank you @Vesper. I will try it. Anyway, can I get your contact? So I can consult to you easier. I do need your help to guide me. But if you can't, no problem, it's ok, just ask by here.

Comment: I might not be available all the time, while StackOverflow is, and there are better people to help you. I suggest you use this site to ask more questions. And, if some answer satisfies you, please accept it as the one you wanted by pressing a "tick" next to it, this helps people around here as well as you.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Vesper. Its ok, then. I've tried your code and it success. Actually, I wanna make that popup invisible when it clicked. How to make it? I don't know the code structure in AS3. I think it already has a function onClick, I mean I want to add another function onClcik so that the popup invisible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you add a listener to your popup MC that will make `popup.visible=false;`, this should do.

Comment: Do I have to make a new private function and function onClick again? @Vesper

Comment: Yes, you can name it any way you like, though. You cannot have two `onClick` functions because of name collision, but naming it `hidePopup` will be even better.